# open url in a uiwebview from different viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have some links which are opened in Safari. Some links are triggered by grouped uitableview cells and some ones by alert buttons.

I would like to open them inside the app. I think I have to use an uiwebview, but what's the better way to do so?

Create a xib with a uiwebview and the corresponding viewcontroller and then push it on the stack with the right url? or?